# What’s the meaning behind the lyric from Captain Fantastic and the Brown Dirt Cowboy “and the ‘68 festival wallflowers are thinning?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-requests, meaning-in-context, lyrics, music

Elton John/Bernie Taupin’s lyric line from Captain Fantastic and the Brown Dirt Cowboy “and the ‘68 festival wallflowers are thinning” has continued to confuse me in its meaning. I understand “‘68 festival wallflowers” may refer to 1968 music festival attendees, the conventional meaning of “wallflowers” alludes to non-participants of dancing, but what do the word choices “wallflowers are thinning” mean?
I have looked at other websites for ideas or interpretations of this phrase to no avail.